# How to switch bar charts using plotly animation in Python?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

Using the interactive plotly library in Python, I'd like to display a bar chart that transitions to different values upon the click of a button (see the animated gif I created in Keynote as a demonstration).

[image]

Starting from the simple code below, how can I create such an animation?

```
import plotly.express as px
model1 = px.bar(x=["Test set 1", "Test set 2"], y=[0.4, 0.8], width=500)
# model2 = px.bar(x=["Test set 1", "Test set 2"], y=[0.6, 0.2], width=500)                                                                                                             
model1.update_layout(xaxis_title="", yaxis_title="Accuracy", yaxis_range=[0,1])
model1.show()
# TODO: Add buttons that allow animated switch between model1 and model2.
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation function has a start frame to end frame, so it is completed with one button instead of two. I have addressed your issue based on the [example](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#simple-play-button) in the reference. We have increased the number of frames to make the animation smoother. The button is now model_A->Model B. And at the end, I made sure to update the title.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

animation_frame = [go.Frame(data=[go.Bar(x=["Test set 1", "Test set 2"], y=[y1,y2])]) 
                   for y1,y2 
                   in zip(np.linspace(0.4,0.6,20),np.linspace(0.8,0.2,20))]
animation_frame[-1]['layout'] = go.Layout(title_text="Model B")

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(x=["Test set 1", "Test set 2"], y=[0.4, 0.8])],
    layout=go.Layout(
        yaxis=dict(range=[0, 1], autorange=False),
        title="Model A",
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(label="Model A->Model B",
                     method="animate",
                     args=[None,{"frame": {"duration": 50, "redraw": True}}]),
                    ])]
    ),
    frames=animation_frame
)

fig.show()
```

[image]